# jasper ireport create a report with parameters without sql query

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm new in jasper ireport , and I want to know if it is possible to create a report only with static text and parameters, but without any sql query.

When I design my report it is possible , but when I try to preview it , I get this message: "The document has no pages" .

I want my java program to pass the parametrs and show them with the static text

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get that message because the "When No Data" property of your report is set to "No Pages". Try setting it to "All Sections, No Detail" and all bands will appear except the Detail band. You can find  this property in the Report Properties section, or you can add it directly in the jrxml:

```
<jasperReport ... whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" ... >
```