# iReport is saying 'The document has no pages'

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports

I am simply writing a report and I am using a database that is connected successfully. The issue I am having is that whenever I try and "**preview**" the report I get the message `"The document has no pages"`. I know that this could either mean I am not using an empty database when I should be but I have a current database connection that passed the "test".

**There are other posts that ask similiar questions to this one but I firmly believe that this issue is different because unlike the others I have read- they are attempting to use EmptyDatabases to do examples and such- I am actually using a real serverside database.**

Thank you for any help!

This is my SQL

---

```
SELECT
 WO."NUM" AS WO_NUM,
 WO."LOCATIONGROUPID" AS WO_LOCATIONGROUPID,
 WO."ID" AS WO_ID,
 UOM."ID" AS UOM_ID,
 UOM."CODE" AS UOM_CODE,
 PART."ID" AS PART_ID,
 PART."NUM" AS PART_NUM,
 PART."STDCOST" AS PART_STDCOST,
 PART."DESCRIPTION" AS PART_DESCRIPTION,
 PARTCOST."ID" AS PARTCOST_ID,
 PARTCOST."AVGCOST" AS PARTCOST_AVGCOST,
 UOMCONVERSION."ID" AS UOMCONVERSION_ID,
 UOMCONVERSION."DESCRIPTION" AS UOMCONVERSION_DESCRIPTION,
 UOMCONVERSION."FACTOR" AS UOMCONVERSION_FACTOR,
 UOMCONVERSION."FROMUOMID" AS UOMCONVERSION_FROMUOMID,
 UOMCONVERSION."MULTIPLY" AS UOMCONVERSION_MULTIPLY,
 UOMCONVERSION."TOUOMID" AS UOMCONVERSION_TOUOMID,
 COSTLAYER."ID" AS COSTLAYER_ID,
 COSTLAYER."ORGTOTALCOST" AS COSTLAYER_ORGTOTALCOST,
 COSTLAYER."PARTID" AS COSTLAYER_PARTID,
 LOCATIONGROUP."ID" AS LOCATIONGROUP_ID,
 LOCATIONGROUP."NAME" AS LOCATIONGROUP_NAME,
 SO."ID" AS SO_ID,
 SO."DATEISSUED" AS SO_DATEISSUED,
 SO."LOCATIONGROUPID" AS SO_LOCATIONGROUPID,
 SO."NUM" AS SO_NUM,
 SO."PRIORITYID" AS SO_PRIORITYID,
 SOITEM."ID" AS SOITEM_ID,
 SO."BILLTONAME" AS SO_BILLTONAME,
 PRODUCT."ID" AS PRODUCT_ID,
 PRODUCT."DESCRIPTION" AS PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
 SOITEM."PRODUCTNUM" AS SOITEM_PRODUCTNUM,
 WO."TYPEID" AS WO_TYPEID,
 WOITEM."ID" AS WOITEM_ID,
 WOITEM."TYPEID" AS WOITEM_TYPEID,
 COMPANY."ID" AS COMPANY_ID,
 COMPANY."NAME" AS COMPANY_NAME
FROM
 "UOM" UOM INNER JOIN "PART" PART ON UOM."ID" = PART."WEIGHTUOMID"
 AND UOM."ID" = PART."SIZEUOMID"
 AND UOM."ID" = PART."UOMID"
 INNER JOIN "PARTCOST" PARTCOST ON PART."ID" = PARTCOST."PARTID"
 INNER JOIN "COSTLAYER" COSTLAYER ON PART."ID" = COSTLAYER."PARTID"
 INNER JOIN "PRODUCT" PRODUCT ON PART."ID" = PRODUCT."PARTID"
 AND PRODUCT."ID" = PART."DEFAULTPRODUCTID"
 INNER JOIN "WOITEM" WOITEM ON PART."ID" = WOITEM."PARTID"
 AND UOM."ID" = WOITEM."UOMID"
 INNER JOIN "WO" WO ON WOITEM."WOID" = WO."ID"
 INNER JOIN "LOCATIONGROUP" LOCATIONGROUP ON WO."LOCATIONGROUPID" = LOCATIONGROUP."ID"
 INNER JOIN "SO" SO ON LOCATIONGROUP."ID" = SO."LOCATIONGROUPID"
 INNER JOIN "SOITEM" SOITEM ON SO."ID" = SOITEM."SOID"
 AND UOM."ID" = SOITEM."UOMID"
 AND PRODUCT."ID" = SOITEM."PRODUCTID"
 AND UOM."ID" = PRODUCT."WEIGHTUOMID"
 AND UOM."ID" = PRODUCT."SIZEUOMID"
 AND UOM."ID" = PRODUCT."UOMID"
 INNER JOIN "UOMCONVERSION" UOMCONVERSION ON UOM."ID" = UOMCONVERSION."TOUOMID"
 AND UOM."ID" = UOMCONVERSION."FROMUOMID",
 "COMPANY" COMPANY
```

Comment: When you execute the query outside of iReport, does it return any data ? If it does, you need to check the structure of your report.

Comment: @ThomCunningham I used iReport to build the query connection so I am not sure if it returns data but it should. EDIT: the tables all do connect some how.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? The first step is to ensure the data you are trying to retrieve exists. Then you need to ensure your query is correct. Execute it outside of iReport to be sure.

Comment: I am using Fishbowl which comes with preexisting tables. My company has the data there and there are plenty of other reports that work with the data. There is already a pre-existing WorkOrderAllocation report but i am trying to make a custom one; i started from scratch. I use the same tables and i still get the errors. I've edited reports before and have been fine but for whatever reason now- it's throwing me that error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jasper ireport create a report with parameters without sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842853/jasper-ireport-create-a-report-with-parameters-without-sql-query)

Comment: This Link may help you regarding your problem [The Document has no page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47102519/4783846)

Answer (score 0):

From the Error it is obvious that the Query is not returning any records.

To Print report even if there is NO DATA without Detail band use the steps below.

From the Report Inspector

- Right click on Report Name
- Click on Properties
- Search for **"When No Data"** property and from the list of drop down select **"All Sections, No Detail"**

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query from your DBMS and see if it returns any results because it seems that there are no records being fetched. You can also change the properties to print report even if there is no data in the detail band as [mani Deep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2750968/mani-deep) has said.